# Why does my connection string not work that I added in my App.config?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have my connection string set up in the app config but I can not get it to find that connectionstring or even see that the connection name currency is in the collection.

I tried to add a version. 
I have tried to adding the provider name to the string.
I have moved it in and out and in again of the path where the database and solution are located.
I have carefully made sure that I was pointed to the right location on my computer.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- CHANGE THIS to match where your solution and sqlite database are -->
    <add name="currency" connectionString="Data Source=F:\CurrencyExercise\currency.db" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And then the code that calls the above.

```
public BaseDataAccess(string connectionName = "currency")
{
    _connectionName = connectionName;
    Connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connectionName].ConnectionString);
    Connection.Open();
}
```

I would expect the code to actually pull back a SQLiteConnection object rather than erroring out.

Comment: Note that at runtime your code tries to load the .config file from the BIN/DEBUG folder where the program runs. Usually this config file is automatically created by Visual Studio copying the file app.config and renamig it to _your_executable_name.exe.config_ Check into this file if you have the correct connection string or not

Comment: It looks like the same location as above. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by saying "_erroring out_"? Note that if your code (accidentally) passes another string to the BaseDataAccess method that is not "_currency_", well, then when trying to find this non-existing connection name in the app.config it would of course error out with some exception... Use the debugger in Visual Studio to figure out and verify what the actual value of the connectionName argument is. Don't trust your assumptions/beliefs of what your code does, it might in reality perhaps do something else...

Comment: By erroring out I mean a null reference error I should have been more specific.  It returns null when it trys to look for "currency" in the connectionstrings and then calling the connectionstring property on null ... boom null ref error.

Comment: If you have diligiently verified the content of the app.config in the bin/debug folders as suggested by Steve, then i doubt your BaseDataAccess method there works with a connectionString that is "_currency_". Use the debugger to verify ;-)

Comment: Also worth noting - as Steve said - is that the app.config in your bin/debug folders will not actually literally be named "app.config"  but rather follows the name of the executable file, like "_NameOfExecutable.exe.config_" or similar. Not that you by accident put a literal "app.config" file there in the bin/debug folders and inspected that ;-) (Well, Steve mentioned it already, i repeat it here just to make sure...)

Comment: Well i definitely doesn't work.  I guess I was under the impression that it would add to the connection strings object one called currency and then that would have its connectionstring property of the connection string.  That doesn't seem to be the case.  I am curious if adding another one would change any of the data or if currency is just not being accounted for at all.

Comment: It appears adding a second item under connection strings did not change the count of the object.  Not sure whats going on now.

Comment: Well, it's rather simple, really. Either the config file in use by your executable does not contain the "currency" connection string (that implies you made some mistake along the way of trying to verify the content of the config file keeping you from confirming this error scenario). Or the `connectionName` string argument is not "_currency_" (implying you made some mistake during debugging, keeping you from confirming that error scenario). Or, 3rd possibility, the error/exception you got is actually not about the ConnectionStrings at all (verify the stack trace of the exception you got)